# Is it possible to combine multiple Application Insights application maps?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights

I currently have a microservice architecture consisting of ~20 services at the moment and each service has its own dedicated application insights instance per environment (dev/test/prod).

What I would like to do, if possible, is aggregate all of the different application maps into one global application map so that I can easily see everything through a single pane of glass (per environment) rather than having to drill into each individual service's application map.

The only way to do this, from what I've found, is to have ever service point to the same app insights resource.  However, I would imagine that this approach would make it difficult to easily track metrics for an individual service, since the metrics would be based off the entire environments architecture rather than each service.  Is there some way to build a workbook that combines all of the application maps?

Any ideas on how to approach this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your microservices are instrumented with Application Insights SDKs and rely on auto instrumentation then it should work out of the box. Application Insights will discover which components a particular app talks to and you should be able to get the full map by clicking on "Update map components".

One app view:

[image]

Whole connected microservice universe view:

[image]

If "Update map components" is greyed out then something wrong with distributed tracing instrumentation.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am trying to view the entire topology of ALL my applications in one place.  I.e. microservices that don't interact with each other, thus would not be 'connected' in a single app insights instance's application map via distributed tracing.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: Ah, got it! No, there is no way of doing it currently. There are two challenges: 1) group concept which determines which applications to show; 2) visualization currently is not actually well designed for disjointed applications.

Comment: Thank you!  So if I were to point all of my prod services to a single prod application insights instance, the view I'm trying to achieve would work?  I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what the downsides of doing that are.  The only downside I have found is that my KPIs/Metrics would be grouped together at a high level, but couldn't I just create KPI metrics and alerts based on queries that filter by an apps cloud role name??

Comment: Both approaches (all apps report to one Application Insights resource and every single app reporting to its own resource) are supported. Many experiences are role name aware (performance, failures, live metrics, application map, transaction search exploration experiences). The only experience which will be less optimal (up to not being able to use it) - Application Insights calculates Standard metrics. This aspect will not make sense (aggregating failures across microservices). But as you mentioned - you can use Logs experience, filter by role name and pin queries to dashboard.